# Python shall print the name of a list given to a function

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing

the task seems so easy - still after hours I can not find a solution.
I want to pass a list and than print the name of the list

- I tried with locals() - but then I get "list" back instead of "march"
- When using str(list), I get the items of the list as a string and again not "march"

  ```
    march = ["A", "B", "C"]

    def func(list):

        print("Name of the List: " +  ????????)

    return None

    func(march)
  ```

It should print:
"Name of list: march"

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables have names, but there is no guarantee that the caller had a variable referring to the argument.

Comment: You can use dictionaries for that

Comment: what would you expect `func([1, 2, 3])` to print? In short, as @user2357112supportsMonica, you can't do this - the function only sees the list, not a variable which happens to hold that list at the time.

Comment: "I want to pass a list and than print the name of the list" - Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel there could be quite a lot of reasons actually, for example You want to know what kind of that it is because values can be integers and if You just have lots of lists that contain integers but each list is meant for different encounters or something like that, but as I suggested the OP can use dictionaries.

Comment: That's not a problem for the called function but for the caller.

Comment: @Justin - because the function will make a join of 2 DataFrames and mention in an added column which lists contain the hit. I solved this problem by adding the name of the list as an extra parameter as a string - but I could save that parameter when I could just take the name of the list and make a string out of it - which of course not happens, as the so created string will show me the content of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this:

```
def name(obj, n):
    namesp = [i for i in n if n[name] is obj]
    yourname = namesp[0]
    print("Name of the List: " + yourname)

# usage
name(march, globals())
```